On the Optimal Transport Distance in Equivalent Martingale Measures
I've been working on this idea for a while and could use some guidance. Right now I'm wondering if the formulas I am writing out make sense. Any help is very much appreciated.
Problem Statement Idea
Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be two distinct Itô processes defined by
$$dX_t = \mu_X(t,X_t)dt + \sigma_X(t,X_t) dW_t^{\mathbb{P}}$$
and
$$dY_t = \mu_Y(t,Y_t)dt + \sigma_Y(t,Y_t) dW_t^{\mathbb{P}}$$
where $dW_t^{\mathbb{P}}$ is a Brownian motion under base measure $\mathbb{P}$. There is a lot of background definitions that I have left out. For this we just should know that Itô processes are Markov processes and assuming some regularity conditions on the drift and diffusion terms, are uniquely identified by their transition density functions.
Girsanov Theory
According to Grisanov theory there exist two equivalent Martigale measures $\mathbb{Q}_X$ and $\mathbb{Q}_Y$ which convert the processes into their equivalent martignale measures (risk neutral measures)
$$dX_t = \sigma_X(t,X_t) dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}_X}$$
and
$$dY_t = \sigma_Y(t,Y_t) dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}_Y},$$
effectively removing the drift from the processes. The transition densities of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ we write as $p_t^X(x)$ and $p_t^Y(y)$ for the processes in the base measure and we write $q_t^X(x)$ and $q_t^Y(y)$ for the transition densities of the processes under $\mathbb{Q}_X$ and $\mathbb{Q}_Y$ respectively.
Radon-Nikodym Derivatives
The change of measure comes by way of the Radon-Nikodym derivatives $Z_t^X(x) = \frac{d\mathbb{Q}_X}{d\mathbb{P}}$ and $Z_t^Y(y) = \frac{d\mathbb{Q}_Y}{d\mathbb{P}}$, defined by
$$Z_t^X​(x) = \exp \left(− \int_0^t \frac{\mu_X​(X_s​,s)}{\sigma_X​(X_s​,s)} ​dW_s^{\mathbb{P}}​−\frac{1}{2}​ \int_0^t \left ( \frac{​\mu_X​(X_s​,s)}{\sigma_X​(X_s​,s)}​ \right)^2 ds \right)$$
and
$$Z_t^X(y) = \exp \left(− \int_0^t \frac{\mu_Y(Y_s​,s)}{\sigma_Y(Y_s​,s)} ​dW_s^{\mathbb{P}}​−\frac{1}{2}​ \int_0^t \left ( \frac{​\mu_Y​(Y_s​,s)}{\sigma_Y​(Y_s​,s)}​ \right)^2 ds \right).$$
Until this point is where I'm pretty confident that the definitions are being stated according to the Girsanov theory and are correct. Please correct me if wrong. This next step is where I am a little more unsure.
Change of Measure Applied to Transition Densities
A Radon-Nikodym derivative can be written like this
$$Z_t(x) = \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} = \frac{q_t(x)dx}{p_t(x)dx} = \frac{q_t(x)}{p_t(x)}$$
where $q_t(x)$ and $p_t(x)$ are the probability density functions associated with the measures $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$. This then allows me to write the transition density of the martingale measures in terms of the base measure and Radon-Nikodym derivatives,
$$q_t^X(x) = p_t^X(x) Z_t^X(x)$$
and
$$q_t^Y(y) = p_t^Y(y) Z_t^Y(y)$$

Until this point I shouldn't have stated anything out of the ordinary,
so I would just like to know if my math is acceptable until this
point?

Here is where I'm trying to go with this
Wasserstein Distance
Define the Wasserstein-1 distance between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a metric space $(M,d)$ as
$$W_1(\mu, \nu) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma (\mu, \nu)} \int_{M \times M} d(x,y) \gamma (x,y) dxdy$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the set of all couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$. A coupling is a joint probability distribution having $\mu$ and $\nu$ as marginals. This is interpreted as finding the smallest transport cost.
This is what I'm trying to say
Let's write the Wasserstein-1 distance between transition densities of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ in the base measure $\mathbb{P}$, $p_t^X(x)$ and $p_t^Y(y)$.
$$W_1^{\mathbb{P}}(X_t, Y_t) = \inf_{\gamma_{\mathbb{P}} \in \Gamma \left(p_t^X(x), p_t^Y(y) \right)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} d(x,y) \gamma_{\mathbb{P}} (x,y) dx dy$$
I emphasize here that the $\gamma_{\mathbb{P}}$ is in the $\mathbb{P}$ measure with the subscript. The $\gamma$ couplings are also referred to as transport maps, because they are interpreted as graphs directing mass from one probability density to another.
So here is the big step. I would like to know that it is possible to arrive at a coupling under the martingale measures $Q_X$ and $Q_Y$, represented by $\gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}$, by applying the Radon-Nikodym derivatives to $\gamma_{\mathbb{P}}$? If so I would be able to write this:
$$\gamma_{\mathbb{P}}(x,y) Z_t^X(x) Z_t^Y(y) = \gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}(x,y)$$
where $\gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} \in \Gamma\left(q_t^X(x), q_t^Y(y) \right)$. If this step is allowable then I would be able to write the transport cost in $\mathbb{Q}_X \times \mathbb{Q}_y$ as a function of the transport cost in the base measure $\mathbb{P}$, like so
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} d(x,y) \gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} (x,y) dx dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} d(x,y) \gamma_{\mathbb{P}}(x,y) Z_t^X(x) Z_t^Y(y)  dx dy.$$
Proof Attempt
As far as I can tell, probability density functions are very similar to measures of measure theory, seemingly interchangeable or identical. Therefore, for the following proof I am going to stay in probability density land. The connection between probability densities and measures is something I'm still learning more about and would love any direction here. An interesting thing is that as far as I can tell, a (change of measure) Radon Nikodym derivative also applies to densities as well as measures, according to the relation given above. In the following, a joint probability density is used in place of a coupling from measure theory, which I think is the correct substitution. Marginal densities are then analogous to the marginal measures of measure theory.
Let $p(x,y)$ be a joint probability density with marginals $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, ie
$$f_X(x) = \int p(x,y) dy$$ and
$$f_Y(y) = \int p(x,y) dx$$.
Let $L(x) = q_X(x)/f_X(x)$ be a Radon-Nikodym derivative which acts as a changes of measure, sending density $f_X$ to $q_X$. Let $R(y) = q_Y(y)/f_Y(y)$ be a Radon-Nikodym derivative that sends density $f_Y$ to $q_Y$.
Let $$g(x,y) = p(x,y)L(x)R(y)$$
The claim is that $g(x,y)$ is a valid joint probability density and that the marginals of $g(x,y)$ are $q_X(x)$ and $q_Y(y)$.
1. $g(x,y)$ is a valid joint density because $$\int \int g(x,y) dx dy = 1$$.
proof (using the law of total probabilty):
$$\int\int p(x,y)L(x)R(y)dx dy = \int R(y)\int p(x|y)f_Y(y)L(x)dx dy$$
$$=\int R(y)f_Y(y) \left( \int p(x|y)L(x)dx \right) dy$$
Looking at the integral inside parentheses, we first note that $\int p(x|y) dx = 1$, as per the definition of joint densities, so $p(x|y)$ qualifies as a probability density. The Radon Nikodym derivative converts one valid density into another, so this integral integrates to 1, $\int p(x|y)L(x) dx = 1$.
$$=\int R(y)f_Y(y) \left( \int p(x|y)L(x)dx \right) dy = \int R(y)f_Y(y) dy$$
The same argument is then made for this integral: valid probability densities integrate to 1.
2.
Computing the marginals of $g(x,y)$.
$$\int g(x,y) dx = \int p(x,y)L(x)R(y) dx = R(y)f_Y(y)\int p(x|y)L(x) dx$$
By the same argument as in the previous step, $\int p(x|y)L(x) dx=1$, so then
$$\int g(x,y) dx = R(y)f_Y(y) = \frac{q_Y(y)}{f_Y(y)} f_Y(y) = q_Y(y)$$
An identical argument shows that
$$\int g(x,y) dy = q_X(x)$$
QED
Is this all allowable? Which points should I take care of the most? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

NB: this is not a true answer to the question, but it was too long for a comment.
I'm not surprised nobody has tried to address this yet. This is a big question with lots of scary elements.
First of all, I'm worried that we might need to take a step back. This seems like it is research work.

If you have an adviser, you should go discuss this with them.
If you don't have an adviser, find one! Research requires guidance.
If your adviser cannot help you with this, are you perhaps going in the wrong direction with your project? Or can you perhaps find together someone that has the right information to help you with this specific point before returning to the work your adviser can help you with?

Hopefully, I'm not completely off base. If so, I apologise, but it felt very important to point out.
Second, I do not understand where you're going with the stochastic processes, but I think your claim might be essentially just about whether you can do a change of variable in your calculation of the wasserstein distance? The answer is yes: there is nothing special about a coupling that prevents you from performing a change of variable. Similarly for a change of base measure / RN derivative. These are both elementary operations of probability theory and there is nothing special about a coupling distribution that makes these operations impossible.
However, unless I'm mistaken, I don't think that's a very productive direction to explore when discussing wasserstein distances / couplings. Doing these elementary manipulations does not change the essence of the problem of finding a minimizer of the distance. Changing the variables probably takes you from a nice distance to a very weird distance instead? Changing the base measure changes nothing, I think?
I'm sorry that I don't have a very positive contribution to make, but I hope it helps a little bit.
Best regards and bon courage with this.

I appreciate your feedback. The part toward the end is pretty much all I was looking for, some confirmation that these basic elements are working as I expected.
I do have an advisor but he has be unable to help me with this project. I met with him a couple of times but didn't get very far.
The Radon Nikodym derivatives in this case are very specific in that they remove the drift from the base process. The eventual conclusion I'm trying to make with tis is that the Wasserstein distance in the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure is strictly less than or equal to the distance in the $\mathbb{P}$ measure

So the this step I've taken here is to represent a distance in $\mathbb{Q}$ in terms of a distance in $\mathbb{P}$. If we assume the coupling in $\mathbb{P}$ is the optimal coupling, what I think may be the case in general is that the transformed coupling in $\mathbb{Q}$ actually results in a smaller distance than in $\mathbb{P}$. Why? Both densities in $\mathbb{Q}$ are martingales (zero mean), but with the same stochastic parts as the base processes. This makes the densities in $\mathbb{Q}$ closer together that in $\mathbb{P}$ where the means could be different.

Well, I think the manipulations are legal and I understand your objective. I remember trying similar things in the past and I think it never got anywhere. That's where I got that experience of this path being a dead-end. But maybe, in the particular case of yours, this is the right proof.

Slightly unrelated, but are you aware of all the analysis work the people like bobkov, ledoux, villani, etc have done to show inequalities on wasserstein distances? They typically link properties of stochastic PDEs, ODEs, and wasserstein distances (and other measures of distance) together some connections which I have always struggled with. This sounds a bit similar to your question here and could be relevant for further progress. Best of luck and bon courage.

Yes, there are some properties that are easy to describe with the more simple math that I have started in this question. Example, using the dual of the Wasserstein distance, we can see that when the means are equal for $\mu$ and $\nu$, the minimum distance of $\int f(x) d \mu - \int f(x) d\nu$ for all Lipshitz-1 functions is zero, while if the means are not equal, we can't make this conclusion. But of course what we want to know is the upper bound is lower, not the lower bound. So, yes, I believe to make the argument one would need to incorporate a PDE like the Fokker-Planck or Feynman-Kac.

FYI this was a leftover project from my doctoral work which I'm trying to pursue again since I still find it pretty interesting, and I really believe the relationship could be true.
